# How can I download the .NET SDK 6.0.125?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-6.0, dotnet-sdk

My goal is to build the ASP.NET Core source code so I can add relevant projects and debug them locally.

I've cloned https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/release/6.0 and followed the steps in:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/docs/BuildFromSource.md.

I was able to restore/build everything without any errors.

I've opened `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.csproj` in VS 2022 v17.9.0 Preview 1.1 and tried to build it, but got this error:

> Error NETSDK1141
> Unable to resolve the .NET SDK version as specified in the global.json located at C:\aspnetcore\global.json.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets   128

This is my `global.json` file:

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.125"
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet": "6.0.125",
    "runtimes": {
      "dotnet/x64": [
        "2.1.30",
        "$(MicrosoftNETCoreBrowserDebugHostTransportVersion)"
      ],
      "dotnet/x86": [
        "$(MicrosoftNETCoreBrowserDebugHostTransportVersion)"
      ],
      "aspnetcore/x64": [
        "3.1.32"
      ]
    },
    "Git": "2.22.0",
    "jdk": "11.0.3",
    "vs": {
      "version": "16.8",
      "components": [
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64"
      ]
    },
    "xcopy-msbuild": "16.5.0-alpha"
  },
  "msbuild-sdks": {
    "Yarn.MSBuild": "1.22.10",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Arcade.Sdk": "6.0.0-beta.23517.3",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Helix.Sdk": "6.0.0-beta.23517.3"
  }
}
```

Based on the first line, I need to download the .NET SDK v6.0.125.

I'm unable to find this version in the archives.

The closest version I found was https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/6.0.12/6.0.12.md.

However, when I download and install this, it shows 6.0.404 as the SDK version, and 6.0.12 as the runtime version:

[image]

I can see I now have these SDKs installed:

[image]

How can I get download .NET SDK 6.0.125?

Comment: It's it right here? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 Scroll down a little bit, there should be: "SDK 6.0.125" (put it in browser search)

Comment: I found it here too:
https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/release-notes/6.0/6.0.25/6.0.125.md

Comment: The Win x64 Installer link is `https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.320-windows-x64-installer` for example.

Comment: Did I misread your question? Don't you want to download that one? What's the issue?

Comment: I couldn't find it then shortly after I posted I found that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0, scroll down a little bit or put "SDK 6.0.125" into your browser Search feature. The download URL for Windows x64 Installer should be https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.320-windows-x64-installer